# Moq Unsupported expression

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, xunit

I was following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking)

I'm trying to build a test project to be able to mock DbContext and services.

My DbContext:

```
public class ProjectDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public ProjectDbContext(DbContextOptions<ProjectDbContext> opt) : base(opt)
    {}
}
```

ISerializable:

```
public interface ISerializable 
{      
    Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync();
    bool SaveChanges();
}
```

Base Service:

```
public class BaseService : ISerializable
{
    protected readonly ProjectDbContext context;

    public BaseService(ProjectDbContext context)
    {
        context = context;   
    }
    
    public async Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        var result = await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return result >= 0;
    }

    public bool SaveChanges()
    {
        var result = context.SaveChanges();
        return result >= 0;
    }
}
```

My Interface for Items Service:

```
public interface IItemsService : ISerializable
{
    Item GetById(Guid id);
}
```

Items Service:

```
public class ItemsService : BaseService, IItemsService
{

    public ItemsService(ProjectDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    { }

    public Item GetById(Guid id)
    {
        return context.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}
```

My test:

```
public class ItemTest
{
    private readonly Mock<DbSet<Item>> _mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Item>>();
    private Mock<ProjectDbContext> _mockContext;

    public ItemTest()
    {
        _mockContext = new Mock<ProjectDbContext >();
        _mockContext.Setup(m => m.Items).Returns(_mockSet.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void GetById_ShouldReturnItemWhenItemExists()
    {
        // Service
        var repository = new ItemsService(_mockContext.Object);

        // Arrange
        var itemId = Guid.NewGuid();

        // Act
        var item = repository.GetById(itemId, CancellationToken.None);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(itemId, item.Id);
    }
}
```

Error message:

> System.NotSupportedException
> Unsupported expression: m => m.Items
> Non-overridable members (here: ProjectDbContext.get_Items) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
> at Moq.Guard.IsOverridable(MethodInfo method, Expression expression) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Guard.cs:line 99
> at Moq.InvocationShape..ctor(LambdaExpression expression, MethodInfo method, IReadOnlyList'1 arguments, Boolean exactGenericTypeArguments, Boolean skipMatcherInitialization, Boolean allowNonOverridable) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\InvocationShape.cs:line 84
> at Moq.ExpressionExtensions.g__Split|5_0(Expression e, Expression& r, InvocationShape& p, Boolean assignment, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\ExpressionExtensions.cs:line 324
> at Moq.ExpressionExtensions.Split(LambdaExpression expression, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\ExpressionExtensions.cs:line 149
> at Moq.Mock.SetupRecursive[TSetup](Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Func'4 setupLast, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Mock.cs:line 601
> at Moq.Mock.Setup(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Condition condition) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Mock.cs:line 505
> at Moq.Mock'1.Setup[TResult](Expression'1 expression) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Mock`1.cs:line 454
> at ItemTest.ctor() in ............\ItemTest.cs:line 20

The error shows following line as non-overridable:

```
_mockContext.Setup(m => m.Items).Returns(_mockSet.Object);
```

I tried to make Items `DbSet` a `virtual` member. Then I started getting:

> Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException
> Can not instantiate proxy of class: ....ProjectDbContext.

Adding a parameterless constructor throws another exception which makes me think I'm doing something wrong. I would appreciate any help regarding to my issue.

Comment: There are couple of purpose built libraries like: [EntityFrameworkCore3Mock](https://github.com/cup-of-tea-dot-be/entity-framework-core3-mock), [EntityFrameworkCore.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing). Have you considered to using them?

Comment: I tried first one, for .Net5 with Moq Integration, same issues

Comment: The [EntityFrameworkCoreMock](https://github.com/cup-of-tea-dot-be/entity-framework-core-mock) supports EFCore 5, not the `EntityFrameworkCore3Mock`. Which one did you try?

Comment: I tried the one that's for EFCore 5

Answer (score 3):

Adding a parameterless constructor works for me, but then you need to add a new 'setup line' where you get a mock of your 'Items':

```
public DbSet<Item> GetItems() {
//your logic
}
```

And add

```
   _mockSet.Setup(i => i).Returns(GetItems());
```

to your test constructor.

Comment: I tried that already. It results in GetById method throwing a NullRefEx.    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelExtensions.FindEntityType(IModel model, Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.CheckState()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()

Comment: Reply to edited answer: That seems like a workaround rather than a robust solution.